# SQL function problem - MOD function with data column does not work

Tags: sql, modulo

I have a problem with function in sql.

SQL function:

```
SELECT resolved_by ,short_description ,case_id ,STATUS ,create_date ,resolved_date ,resolution, datediff(day, create_date, resolved_date) - 1 - MOD (create_date, 1) + MOD(resolved_date, 1)
FROM booker.o_remedy_tickets
WHERE assigned_to_group IN ( 'emae' ) AND create_date > '2020-11-17'
```

In excel it works and mod function looks like:

```
=NETWORKDAYS(E2,F2)-1-MOD(E2,1)+MOD(F2,1)
```

But I have no idea how to format this mod function to sql.

create_date table is in format like: `2020-11-11 07:58:16.0`

resolved_date in format like: `2020-11-11 09:38:38.0`

I have error:

> Invalid operation: function mod(timestamp without time zone, integer) does not exist.

I am in stuck...

If someone have any idea I really appreciate it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please explain the logic you want.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: What's the database you want do run this SQL code at?

Comment: Neither MySQL nor SQL Server have a direct equivalent function to `NETWORKDAYS()`. Even if you solve your problem with `MOD()` you won't get the number of working days with `DATEDIFF()`.

Comment: I would like to count: Tickets Inflow. It is a datebase with tickets which are resolved by employers. I extracting data from sql with syntax: SELECT resolved_by ,short_description ,case_id ,STATUS ,create_date ,resolved_date ,root_cause_details ,resolution FROM booker.o_remedy_tickets WHERE assigned_to_group IN ( 'emae' ) AND create_date > '2020-11-06'. I am getting excel file and the rest I count in excel with formula: NETWORKDAYS(E2,F2)-1-MOD(E2,1)+MOD(F2,1) where E2=create date --F2=resolvd date. But i have no idea how to convert in on to have whole syntax prepared in sql without use excel.